# Trace width calculator for any material

Tags: pcb, trace

I'd really like to make a calculator which outputs the width of a conductor given the following inputs:  resistivity, trace thickness, trace length, applied power (or current and voltage), not to exceed dT of 10C.

Or in other words, I'd really like a trace width calculator which could be used for any material, not just copper, at any thickness (not just 1/2oz, 1oz, etc).

Any idea on which equation(s) to use?

Comment: Recent article in Printed Circuit Design and Fab Magazine: [Trace Current-Temperature Relationships](http://pcdandf.com/pcdesign/index.php/magazine/10122-thermal-management-1506).  (Just piling on references.)

Comment: This is one of the best ones I have found
http://www.4pcb.com/trace-width-calculator.html

Answer (score 2):

If you have equations for (say) 1oz (34.79um) copper, simply pre-scale the equivalent current based on the resistivity and trace thickness.

If the trace is carrying 0.5A and the material has bulk resistivity 3 times that of copper and it's 60um thick, then it's the same as a copper trace carrying 0.5 * sqrt(3) * sqrt(34.79um/60um) = 0.66A.

Heat loss should not be affected significantly by trace thickness or resistivity.